# Mobile Launcher Design

Tags: apollo-program, space-shuttle, launch-site, acoustic-sound-suppression

When looking at the Apollo and space shuttle mobile launch platforms side by side, I noticed that the exhaust ports look different and judging by the internal structure of the platform, it seems that the area where the water birds are for the space shuttle launchers were the original exhaust ports for the Apollo missions. Is this true?
[image: Apollo ML]

[image: Space Shuttle MLP]

Comment: What do you mean by "water birds"? I suspect you are referring to the Tail Service Masts, which do not spray water.

Comment: I think he's referring to the water deluge system, those upright pipes are called rain birds.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Hobbes answer, heres an overlay of the MLP when it was for Apollo and when it was for STS:

[image]

Dark ovals shows the 6 rain birds (Sound Suppression System) location after STS conversion.

Also shown are the interfaces for the launcher/tower when it was for Apollo.

Added a photo from when Mobile Launcher 3 was reconstructed to be Mobile Launcher Platform No. 1 for the STS, 24 September 1976. Goes to show how much was changed.

[image]

http://images.ksc.nasa.gov/photos/1976/captions/KSC-76C-2754.html

Comment: That's a useful schematic.

Comment: One of the rainbirds and the entry hatch on MLP 1. Photographed Oct 2006. https://i.imgur.com/pBxr66E.jpg

Comment: Funny to see the entry hatch remain all the way from the Apollo days.

Answer (score 1):

The exhaust openings were [modified](https://www.primidi.com/mobile_launcher_platform/evolution/space_shuttle):

> The Space Shuttle Main Engine (SSME) vented its exhaust through the original opening used for the Saturn rocket exhaust. Two additional holes were added to vent exhaust from the Solid Rocket Boosters that flanked the external fuel tank.

The area where the rain birds are used to have the [Launch Umbilical Tower](https://apollomaniacs.com/apollo/mobile_launcher_en.htm) in the Apollo era.